# Grouping a datatable using Linq generates error: "Definition of method <method> is not accessible in this context"

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, group-by, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get distinct usernames from a datatable using Linq and VB.NET 2017.
I have read a lot of articles but could not solve the problem
This is the error:

> Definition of method myGroup is not accessible in this context

And this is my query

```
Dim users2 = From row As DataRow In ReportTable
             Group row By New With {.name = row.Item("user_name"), .code = row.Item("user_code")} Into myGroup '<-- Error
             Select myGroup
```

But it's based on what Microsoft reference describes:

```
    var queryLastNames =
    from student in students
    group student by student.LastName into newGroup
    orderby newGroup.Key
    select newGroup;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: Do you have a method named `myGroup` ?

Comment: Absolutely not. I just want to group items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Grouping` statement is not correct. The alias name for grouping must declared before grouping. The `myGroup` declared and then assigned using `Into Group` before selecting values. Also, missed `Key` - keyword before the grouping columns.

```
        Dim users2 = From row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable()
                             Group row By myGroup = New With 
                             {
                              Key .name = row.Item("user_name"), 
                              Key .code = row.Item("user_code")
                             } Into Group
                         Select myGroup
```

[VB.Net Fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdgyDP)

Comment: Thanks. It works without error but I expected that results should be unique, but it's format is different from what I read in microsoft reference. I added the Microsoft reference to the question

Comment: That reference is for C#, not for VB.NET.

Comment: @rostamiani I have updated the answer. You need to specify the Key columns for grouping. Fiddle updated with correct grouping samples.